# Fluent NHibernate SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, fluent-nhibernate

I'm developing a .net project and I use the first time SQL Server 2012 with fluent nhibernate when I running my project I get the following error =>

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: Data Source
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please        review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: Data Source

My configuration syntax

```
Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(
      MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c.FromAppSetting("ConnectionString")))
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
      .CurrentSessionContext<T>()
      .BuildSessionFactory();
```

and my connection string in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=ExcelReport; Integrated Security=true;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've tried various ways but I couldn't fix the problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: When you are connected to SQL Server Via SSMS , run this `SELECT @SERVERNAME` in a query window, and use the returned value in your Data Source Proerty.

Comment: I've tried but It doesn't work thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<connectionStrings>` are not the same as `<appSettings>`.

You connection string is not in an app setting.

You connection string is in `<connectionStrings>`

You therefore need to use `FromConnectionStringWithKey` instead of `FromAppSetting`.

For example:

```
c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString")
```

Your configuration syntax should be:

```
Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(
      MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString")))
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
      .CurrentSessionContext<T>()
      .BuildSessionFactory();
```